# How to write a Solr query to get all the documents by ids

Tags: solr, spring-data-solr

I want to write a query that returns the documents with ids. For example, I want documents with ids 1-10. I want to write a query that will enable me doing that.
Like `q=id:1,q=2.....` How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways:

```
q=id:(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

or

```
q=id:1 OR id:2 OR id:3 OR id:4 OR id:5 ..
```

or

```
q=id:[1 TO 10]
```

or with `q.op=OR`:

```
q=id:1 id:2 id:3 id:4 id:5 ..
```